# How to insert GET variables in URL and redirect by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to check the URL and when two specific GET variables are missing push them in the URL and redirect to the new URL.

For example I have made the following `.htaccess` file.

The aim is to check if `sap-language` or `hc_reset` are missing then push them in the URL!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|json|xml|properties|svg|woff2|ttf|ico|php|woff|eot)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^sap-language=.*$
RewriteRule .* /index.html?sap-language=de\&hc_reset [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

**The problem is with this solution it will remove all other GET variables!**

For example the following URL `/index.html?xyz=1` will change to `/index.html?sap-language=de&hc_reset`.

Also the other problem is that `sap-language` must be placed in the first place, and the following URL also will be overwritten:   `/index.html?xyz=1&sap-language=de&hc_reset`

However I am looking for a solution that keep the other GET variables and hashes in the place and just injects these 2 GET variables i.e. `sap-language` and `hc_reset` if any of them is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule with `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|json|xml|properties|svg|woff2|ttf|ico|php|woff|eot)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)sap-language= [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)hc_reset(?:[=&]|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html?sap-language=de&hc_reset [L,QSA,R=302,NE]
```